# Returning a serialized list of a reverse relation - all object instances voted upon by current user

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

I have Users 'favouriting' Content and Outlets, using [django-vote](https://github.com/Beeblio/django-vote). I want an endpoint view in Django Rest Framework that will return a (ContentSerializer) list of all Content voted upon (favourited) by the current logged-in user.

But while [django-vote](https://github.com/Beeblio/django-vote) gives a way to retrieve a list of users who voted on a particular Content instance via `content.likes.users()` it does not give a way to retrieve all the Content instances a user has voted on.

My ideal result is that visiting `/content/favourited/` will give a json using ContentSerializer that lists all Content where `content.likes.exists(user)` is `True`. How do I do this efficiently?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from vote.managers import VotableManager

class Content(models.Model):
    # ... fields here
    likes = VotableManager()
```

**views.py**

```
class ContentViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Content to be viewed
    """
    queryset = Content.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ContentFilter

    @list_route(permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def favourited(self, request):    
        """
        Returns a list of favourited content for the current logged-in user.
        """
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            **DO SOMETHING**
            return **SOMETHING**

    @detail_route(permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def like(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        Toggles favourited "like" on content for the current logged-in user.
        """
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            liked = self.get_object().likes.exists(request.user)
            if liked is False:
                self.get_object().likes.up(request.user)
                return Response({'status': 'liked'})
            elif liked is True:
                self.get_object().likes.down(request.user)
                return Response({'status': 'unliked'})
        else:
            return Response({'status': 'unauthenticated'})

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        # this will throw an error if using django rest swagger
        if self.action == 'list':
            return ContentSerializer
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return ContentDetailSerializer
        return ContentSerializer
```

Also on a secondary note, I was wondering where should this "favourited content" endpoint ideally be – under `/content` by identifying the logged-in user via the `request`, or under `/users` using a `pk`?

```
http://example.com/api-v1/users/1/favourited-content/
```

or

```
http://example.com/api-v1/content/favourited/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad that you like `django-vote`. I have merged a pull request which add a new api to get all instances voted by a specify user. You can download the latest version on pypi now.

Comment: It seems `pip install django-vote` installs version 1.2 while your update is version 1.1.0

Comment: I was able to install using `pip install django-vote==1.1.0`

Comment: Just fix it. By the way, if you want the user's favourited content to be viewed by other users you can use url pattern one, if you want to limit favourited content to the user you can use url pattern two.